# Google Cloud - Deploy as Container from GCR - Ports not exposed in docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-os

I have created a GCP VM instance, with option `Deploy as Container` pointing to an image in my private GCR(nginx customized).

Also while creating the instance, I had given allow 'https' and 'http' traffic.

Though the application is working fine, on connecting the instance via `ssh` and inspecting docker containers 
(`docker ps`)
I see the container ports are not exposed. Wondering how the http/https request are handled by the container here via the instance??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the deploying containers option in GCE it runs docker with access to the host network.

From the relevant [gcp docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers) :

> Containerized VMs launch containers with the network set to host mode.
>   A container shares the host network stack, and all interfaces from the
>   host are available to the container.

More detailed info on the different network modes [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings).

Answer (score 0):

Other than what @Stefan R has told, you should also use PORT number greater than 1000 as auto deployed container images aren't run as root and hence can't access privileged ports.

https://www.staldal.nu/tech/2007/10/31/why-can-only-root-listen-to-ports-below-1024/

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=privileged+ports+linux&oq=privileged+ports+linux